# Using VARCHAR as PRIMARY KEY for an 'ORPHAN' table

Tags: sql, database, varchar, sql-types

I'm to create an orphan table (no relationships with any other table whatsoever) that contains 3 columns.

- Col1 - String field - VARCHAR(32) - Contains unique data not more than 32 characters
- Col2 - String field - TEXT - Contains larger non-unique data of characters
- Col3 - Numeric (Bool) - INT(1) - 0/1 for Flagging

I'm thinking of using Col1 as my PRIMARY KEY. I have done some research and see people argue that using a meaningless INT column as a PRIMARY KEY to avoid Foreign Key/Storage issues is the way to go.

However, IMO, since this is an orphan table, it should not matter. Besides, I would require to place an INDEX on Col1 anyway.

As a side note, I'm not expecting more than ~1000 rows in this table.

Thoughts please.

Comment: I wanted to know if my situation fits using VARCHAR as PRIMARY KEY. Sorry, I assumed the question was evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If col1 is your *real* primary key, there is no reason not to use it. Especially if the table is that tiny.

You would need to maintain a unique index on that column anyway, so by adding an artificial primary key you just add more overhead fon insert and delete operations (as two indexes must be maintained).

Unless you are referencing that PK from really, really many other rows (and other tables) you should just go with what is the natural primary for your business rules.

Answer (score 2):

I'd still just use an INT PK and put an index on COL1.  I suppose you could use COL1 as the index if you can ensure that nothing will ever be joined to that table, but if nothing else the index will give you an idea of the order in which items are added/deleted from the table.  I also like to add an IsActive boolean so that you never delete anything and a DateCreated datetime to almost every table.

Comment: +1 for IsActive and TIMESTAMP ideas. That would definitely help my case. Still not convinced on the INT PK.

Comment: Well, the other commenters are right in that if the situation is as you describe - small table and nothing joins to it - then you're probably fine using the varchar.  I still wouldn't because I like having a numbered list because it's handy for things like exporting into Excel so you can keep them in order when you sort them.  I guess unless you have a good reason not to, I'd use the INT.  Also, use DATETIME rather than TIMESTAMP: timestamp doesn't do what most people think. It's really just for tracking if a row has changed but it doesn't tell you when like a datetime does.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't need the INT PK then. I'm not planning on exporting to excel, nor sort the columns (even while querying). Agreed on DATETIME. I don't need to track changes either. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see where you are coming from but it just makes sense to index the first column anyway. It may be because I am used to excel but the usefulness of the initial column for a primary key also has an order to it along with readability while debugging or capturing data. If you use a more random generated number you still would be searching through a few hundred rows looking for a hard to distinguish key. In the end I highly recommend the extra column of ints. It is well worth it.

Comment: I forgot to ask if you would be deleting data? It may sounds dumb but if you arent, it almost adds another plus to adding the extra column for keys because you have a quick check for the total amount of entries. If you are deleting, it is a quick check for where items were deleted from your DB. Not entirely useful but it is a potential check that would not otherwise be there.

Comment: Thank you. I did not plan about deleting data. The data is static configuration settings that need to be stored on DB. I would mostly never delete any rows. Only UPDATE. Any thoughts on performance of UPDATE?

Comment: It wont make a difference on the performance of update weather you use one column vs another especially with under 1000 rows. **I never really thought about if it would be quicker to query for an in ID or a character ID honestly. I am not entirely sure since by then it would be running against the  database.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i do any database tables i keep my INT column.
I believe its faster to compare numbers then strings.

So it all depends how ofter you will query the database for info and compare strings in there.

Comment: That's the point. I would never use the INT column (if I introduce it) to compare. I'll always be querying the table based on Col1

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unclear what the question is.  Judging from the answers, I've deduced it down to two plausible questions:

1. **Is it okay to use a VARCHAR instead of an INTEGER as a primary key?**

   - Yes it is okay to use a VARCHAR instead.
     In many cases it is preferred, especially if your table is expected to grow beyond 2,147,483,647 records (yes this happens).  Performance-wise, even if INTs had a minimal speed advantage, on a ~1000 record table, you would not see it.  Designated PKs are indexed by default.  The one problem is that you'll lose any auto-generating sequence that the database can do for you.
2. **Is it okay to use your unique COL1 field as a primary key, instead of some other unique ID field?**

   - Yes it is okay.
     The whole notion of having a primary key is to establish a unique field.  What you're losing, though, may be some intrinsic comprehension.  When other users want to join on that table, it's far easier to understand that `id` is a unique field, whereas `col1` (some varchar) may or may not be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In your given scenario, it should be okay. If the scope does grow up then you can always introduce an auto_increment PK column. Just make sure that your field is both indexed and unique.